What processes are systemd-resolved?
What is systemd-resolved?
When I search the web, I come across stub resolvers, but stub resolvers are basically provided to the app side in the form of a library, I believe it is not provided as a process.
In short, I thought that systemd-resolved is not a stub resolver, but a kind of service that caches more between the stub resolver and the DNS cache server.
My assumption is as follows.
process->stub resolver->systemd-resolved->dns cache server ->dns server
This is on a Ubuntu installation, if that matters.

"stub resolvers are basically provided to the app side in the form of a library" ... That's how stub functions usually work, yes, but how do you stub something at the remote end of a network call without patching everything that makes that network call?

Read man systemd-resolved or see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html
First, when requesting, for example, the IP address of www.example.com, the "Stub" resolver in the $USER program uses a subroutine in a shared library that looks at the file /etc/resolv.conf. The $USER resolver sends its request to the server specified in the file. If the server specified is 127.0.0.53#53 the request goes to localhost (all 127.*.*.* addresses mean localhost), TCP/IP port 53. To see the program listening to port 53, use the terminal command sudo lsof -i:53. The server listening to port 53 is probably systemd-dnsmasq, a "forwarding" DNS server. It maintains a local DNS cache, reads /etc/hosts, and knows who to ask when a cache miss happens, probably the DNS server provided by your DHCP server. Eventually, the answer (Either the IP address of www.example.com is 1.2.3 4, or an error response) comes back, and the $USER program opens a TCP/IP connection to 1.2.3.4, or takes the error path.
